# How to register this class using autofac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have this class where currently i registered them using AddScoped from the service method. But how do i register them using autofac? I'am trying to get use to the autofac.

Already tried to use Autofac to register but when run the program it does not do anything.

The class

```
public class WaktuSolatServiceApi  : IWaktuSolatServiceApi
{
    private readonly string URL = string.Empty;

    HttpClient client;

    public WaktuSolatServiceApi(HttpClient client, IOptions<WaktuUrl> 
 settings)
    {
        this.client = client;
        URL = settings.Value.URL;
    }
}

public interface IWaktuSolatServiceApi
{
    Task<Solat> GetAsyncSet();
}
```

Autofac

```
public static class ContainerConfig
{
    public static IContainer Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load(nameof(WaktuSolatApi)))
            .Where(c => c.Namespace.Contains("Services"))
            .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name)).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        //builder.Register(c => new WaktuSolatServiceApi(c.Resolve<HttpClient>(), c.Resolve<IOptions<WaktuUrl>>()));

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
        Configuration = configuration;
        var container = ContainerConfig.Configure();
}
```

Currently i use this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddService(this IServiceCollection 
services)
{
        services.AddScoped<IWaktuSolatServiceApi, WaktuSolatServiceApi>();
        services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();

        return services;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Autofac provides three typical ways to identify services. The most common is to identify by type.

```
builder.RegisterType<WaktuSolatServiceApi>().As<IWaktuSolatServiceApi>();
```

This example associates the IWaktuSolatServiceApi typed service with the WaktuSolatServiceApi component. Instances of the component can be retrieved using the service type with the Resolve() method:

```
var r = container.Resolve<IWaktuSolatServiceApi>();
```

**and finally if it is not your answer , look at this [Autofac Document](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) for more information**

Answer (score 0):

You should to configure your options.

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));
```